# how to see the element in emulator ui in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am adding a scrollbar to my app, this is my code:

```
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
 return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragStart: _onHorizontalDragStart,
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: _onHorizontalDragUpdate,
      onHorizontalDragEnd: _onHorizontalDragEnd,
      child: Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
          ),
          color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          child: CupertinoScrollbar(
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: buildListView(item, context),
            ),
          )));
```

but in the UI, I did not find the ScrollBar. How to make the scrollbar show on the UI? or like inspect element like html in Chrome. this is the UI:

[image]

I have wake up the Flutter Inspector, but when I click the element, nothing happen in the emulator. Now I am using `SingleChildScrollView`:

```
SingleChildScrollView buildListView(Item item, BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => CommonUtils.launchUrl(item.link),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Text(
                    item.title == "" ? "Comment" : item.title,
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (item.domain != "")
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      navToChannelDetail();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      item.domain,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    )),
              ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                      text: item.author,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: " ${String.fromCharCode(8226)} ",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: item.ago,
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (item.content != "")
              Html(
                data: item.content,
                style: {
                  "body": Style(
                    fontSize: FontSize(19.0),
                  ),
                },
                //sonLinkTap: (url) => CommonUtils.launchUrl(url),
              ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          if (item.isFav == 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              onPressed: () => touchFav("unfav", FavStatus.UNFAV),
                            ),
                          if (item.isFav != 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
                              onPressed: () => touchFav("fav", FavStatus.FAV),
                            ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "${item.favCount}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          if (item.isUpvote == 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                              onPressed: () => touchUpvote("unupvote", UpvoteStatus.UNUPVOTE),
                            ),
                          if (item.isUpvote != 1)
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                              onPressed: () => touchUpvote("upvote", UpvoteStatus.UPVOTE),
                            ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "${item.upvoteCount}",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption!.copyWith(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                  ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Feather.share_2,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () => handleShare(id: item.id, title: item.title, postUrl: item.link),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the `_scrollController` to `ListView`

You can try this , I hope to help you :

```
return Container(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
    ),
    color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    child: CupertinoScrollbar(
      isAlwaysShown: true,
      controller: _scrollController,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
            itemCount: 500,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder:(_, index){
          return Text('Index Number : '+index.toString());
        }),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: I am using `SingleChildScrollView` now. And I am also add `_scrollController` @Adel B-Lahlouh